# How can we mock a casted state in Corda written in kotlin using mockito?

Tags: kotlin, casting, mockito, corda

signedTx.tx.outputStates.last() as myState---This is my requirement.I have to mock this where signedTx.tx.outputStates.last() returns a ContractState and myState is my customized state.

`val response = JSONObject()
val owner=proxy.nodeInfo().legalIdentities.first()

```
        val signedTx = proxy.startFlowDynamic(myFlow.myFlowInitiator::class.java ,
                Data,
                status,
                subStatus,
                owner
        ).returnValue.getOrThrow()

        val outputState=signedTx.tx.outputStates.last() as myState
       
        if( myState.action.equals("submit",false)){
            response["Response"] = "Success"
            response["message"] = "All goood"
            response["TxnId"] = signedTx.id.toString()
            response["Id"] = outputState.id
            ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(response)

        }`
```

Comment: Could you add more details like what you are doing and what's not working? Some code snippets would be great to be able to help you.

Comment: I have added the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

it's not super clear what the issue you're running into is but take a look at this code example for how to mock nodes on a network and simulate a transaction to get a state on the other side.

```
@Test
public void flowReturnsCorrectlyFormedPartiallySignedTransaction() throws Exception {
    SignedTransaction stx = issueIOU(new IOUState(Currencies.POUNDS(10), b.getInfo().getLegalIdentities().get(0), a.getInfo().getLegalIdentities().get(0)));
    issueCash(Currencies.POUNDS(5));
    IOUState inputIOU = stx.getTx().outputsOfType(IOUState.class).get(0);
    IOUSettleFlow.InitiatorFlow flow = new IOUSettleFlow.InitiatorFlow(inputIOU.getLinearId(), Currencies.POUNDS(5));
    Future<SignedTransaction> futureSettleResult = a.startFlow(flow);

    mockNetwork.runNetwork();

    SignedTransaction settleResult = futureSettleResult.get();
    // Check the transaction is well formed...
    // One output IOUState, one input IOUState reference, input and output cash
```

Source for this example of running a test transaction on a mocknetwork:

https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Advanced/obligation-cordapp/workflows/src/test/java/net/corda/samples/flow/IOUSettleFlowTests.java